# Changing the path structure of my page

Tags: php

So for awhile I've been stuck on this assignment. We are supposed to create a user account page and have an image uploaded with it as well.

Everything has gone well, I got the information into the database and the image even uploads just fine on my server. 
But the one problem is displaying the image.

As you see here on the part where I embed the picture into the page, it comes up as an invalid picture. I finally decided to take a look at the actual source and it said that it is coming from a non existent folder that is relative to the folder it is in now. The folder the I want it to reach is up one level. But I don't want to move this php up one level because it destroys the folder structure of my site. So I just wanted an absolute path instead of a relative path. Or is this not the problem?

```
   <?php

    $userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];

    require_once 'config/connection.php';


    $query = "SELECT * from user WHERE user_id= {$userid};";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);

    if ($result) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $username = html_entity_decode($row['username']);
        $email = $row['email'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $filename = get_web_path($row['user_pic_path']);

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Wonder Penguin - Registration Successful! </title> 
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    echo "<h2> Registration is successful! </h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> User ID </th>";
    echo "<th> Username </th>";
    echo "<th> Email </th>";
    echo "<th> Date </th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$userid</td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<td>$username</td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<td>$email</td>";
    echo" <br>";    
    echo "<td>$date</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "$filename";
    } else {
        echo "<p> Unable to insert the record for some reason... </p>";
        }
    echo "<p><img src='Wonder Penguin/files/$filename' alt='product image'></p>";



    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

As you see here on the part where I embed the picture into the page, it comes up as an invalid picture. I finally decided to take a look at the actual source and it said that it is coming from a non existent folder that is relative to the folder it is in now. The folder the I want it to reach is up one level. But I don't want to move this php up one level because it destroys the folder structure of my site. So I just wanted an absolute path instead of a relative path. Or is this not the problem?

This file is on "Wonder Penguin/PHP/registersuccessful.php" but it links to a file that is in "Wonder Penguin/files". So it's basically looking for a file that's on "Wonder Penguin/PHP/files" when that folder doesn't even exist.

Thank you for all of your time!

Comment: Be careful... you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  You should be learning prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  If you are not being taught this method, you are being taught incorrectly.  Also, use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data you use in the context of HTML.  This function ensures that reserved characters are escaped correctly, generating valid HTML and preventing some types of XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`../` will get you up a level without needing absolute URLs:

```
echo "<p><img src='../files/$filename' alt='product image'></p>";
```

Comment: Very simple solution. Thank you!